# TYPO3 Gridelements w/DataProcessing and FLUID no content

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I used Gridelements a while now. I used the following code:

TypoScript (Gridelements (deprecated) (gridelements)):

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  2col < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  2col.cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  2col.cObject.file = {$resDir}/Private/Partials/Gridelements/2spalten.html
}
```

FLUID Template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_0}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_1}
    </div>
</div>
```

PageTS:

```
tx_gridelements.setup {
    2col {
        title = Two Columns
        config {
            colCount = 2
            rowCount = 1
            rows {
                1 {
                    columns {
                    1 {
                        name = Links
                        colPos = 0
                    }
                    2 {
                        name = Rechts
                        colPos = 1
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now I want to use "Gridelements w/DataProcessing (recommended) (gridelements)" because the other one is deprecated. But all I see is the error:

> Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->2col"
> in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected
> template file (Standard/2col.html). The following paths were checked:
> /var/www/html/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/,
> /var/www/html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/gridelements/Resources/Private/Templates/,
> /var/www/html/typo3/typo3conf/ext/dev_layout/Resources/Private/Templates/

If I write this in my TypoScript code:

```
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup =< lib.contentElement
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup {
    templateRootPaths {
        20 = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/Gridelements/
    }
}
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
tt_content.gridelements_view < tt_content.gridelements_pi1
```

And when I create the named file, the error no longer appears. But there is no output. I see the divs but no content. How can I switch from deprecated gridelements to dataprocessing gridelements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Template:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<div class="row">
    <f:if condition="{children}">
        <f:for each="{children.1}" as="column" key="columnNumber">
            <div id="c{data.uid}-{columnNumber}" class="grid-column grid-column-{columnNumber} col-lg-6">
                <f:for each="{column}" as="child">
                    <f:render partial="Child"
                        arguments="{data: child.data, children: child.children, options: options, settings: settings}" />
                </f:for>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </f:if>
</div>
</html>
```

For two different cols

```
<div id="c{data.uid}-{columnNumber}" class="grid-column grid-column-{columnNumber} {f:if(condition: '{columnNumber} == 0', then: 'col-lg-3', else: 'col-lg-9')}">
```

My column numbers are left 0 and right 1

TS in dataprocessing.10:

```
2col {
  as = children
    options {
      resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation is wrong you need this

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 =< lib.contentElement
```

TSconfig:
Default gridelements TSConfig

Answer (score 1):

"The documentation is wrong you need this"

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 =< lib.contentElement
```

Sure? I could still use the original as it is written in the example for w / DataProcessing:

```
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup =< lib.contentElement
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this code

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  2col < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  2col.cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  2col.cObject.file = {$resDir}/Private/Partials/Gridelements/2spalten.html
}
```

does not match the new static you included.

Take a look at the basic example shown in the documentation:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/gridelements/stable/Chapters/DataProcessing/Index.html

```
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup =< lib.contentElement
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup {
  templateName.field = tx_gridelements_backend_layout
  templateName.ifEmpty = GridElement
  layoutRootPaths {
    1 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Layouts/
  }
  partialRootPaths {
    1 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Partials/
  }
  templateRootPaths {
    1 = EXT:gridelements/Resources/Private/Templates/
  }
  dataProcessing {
    10 = GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\DataProcessing\GridChildrenProcessor
    10 {
      default {
        as = children
        # Default options of the grid children processor
        # Change them according to the needs of your layout
        # Read more about it in the TypoScript section of the manual
        # options {
          # sortingDirection = ASC
          # sortingField = sorting
          # recursive = 0
          # resolveFlexFormData = 1
          # resolveBackendLayout = 1
          # respectColumns = 1
          # respectRows = 1
        # }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you want to add your own templates and rendering configurations you just need to add something in `dataProcessing.10` like

```
dataProcessing {
  10 = GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\DataProcessing\GridChildrenProcessor
  10 {
    2col {
      as = columncontent
      options {
        resolveFlexFormData = 0
        respectRows = 0
      }
    }
    accordion {
      as = accordionitems
      options {
        resolveFlexFormData = 0
        respectRows = 0
        respectColumns = 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The name of the variables can still be `children`, but it might be more comfortable to deal with variable names matching then purpose of your template.

Comment: I've tried this but i dont get an output. This {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_0} doesn't work anymore?

Comment: If you want to work with any of the virtual fields called "tx_gridelements_view_column_x", you have to stick to the old  static template, since they will be generated by the userFunc only.

If you go for the new dataProcessing approach, those fields are superfluous, because Fluid can deal with multideminsional arrays. Just take a look at the templates, layouts and partials shipped with Gridelements to see how it's done.

Comment: How should my Template look like? Is there maybe a demo for a 2 column layout? TypoScript / Template / TSConfig?
Thank You

Comment: The example templates are shipped with Gridelements already. Just take a look into the Resources folder and you will find everything you need.

Comment: I used the Child.html for my 2cols.html now it works. But how can i add different classes like col-lg-8 and col-lg-4?
And in the documentation is an error. It says ```lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup =< lib.contentElement
``` but i think it has to be ```tt_content.gridelements_pi1 =< lib.contentElement```

Comment: You can add as many classes as you like to your own templates based on those examples. There are several options to achive that i.e. using a fluid f:foreach loop and assigning classes based on the iterator provided by that viewhelper, so that the first column can get another class as the second one.

You can even hardcode the layout without a column foreach loop by directly assigning the array key of a specific column to a DIV and just looping over the children of that column.

Comment: i would like to hardcode the output. How can i do this?

Comment: Write some HTML into your template that already contains the necessary <div> tags and CSS classes for the two different columns. Now put a <f:foreach> viewhelper into each of those columns and have them loop over the specific sub-array of the matching column.

Depending on your dataProcessing configuration those arrays will i. e. be found at children.0.columns.0 or children.0.columns.1 - use <f:debug> to get an overview of the actual array structure in your case.

Comment: Thank you. I think im done. Posted my code to help others

Answer (score 0):

I got same error after i upgrade to latest TYPO3 10 version from Typo3 9 and include Gridelement (Recommended).

`Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->1" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/1.html). The following paths were checked:`

**Solution:**

1. Rename gridelement template name with 1.html for gridelement uid=1
2. Change TS like:

> ```
> tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
>   templateRootPaths {
>       15 = EXT:site_config/Resources/Private/Templates/Extensions/Grid-Templates/
>   }
>
>   dataProcessing {
>     10 {
>       default {
>         options {
>             resolveFlexFormData = 1
>               resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
>           }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Inside **Grid-Templates** add your gridelement templates like 1.html, 2.html etc.
3) change template(HTML) code like this:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<div class="row">
    <f:if condition="{children}">
        <f:for each="{children.1}" as="column" key="columnNumber">
            <div id="c{data.uid}-{columnNumber}" class="grid-column grid-column-{columnNumber} col-lg-6">
                <f:for each="{column}" as="child">
                    <f:render partial="Child"
                        arguments="{data: child.data, children: child.children, options: options, settings: settings}" />
                </f:for>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </f:if>
</div>
</html>
```